# Regex prefer higher length in second group

Tags: regex

Lets say I have the following 2 strings:

> '506'
>   '1008'

I want to extract the 5 and the 06 from the string and 10 and 08 from the second. I came up with the following regex:

```
(\d{1,2})(\d{1,2})
```

This matches 50 and 6 and 10 and 08. This is not completely what I want. I need to match 5 and 06 instead of 50 and 6. How do I indicate I want the second group to receive the higher length?

Comment: Just fix to 2 the lenght of the second group.

Comment: Omg You are a genius sometimes the easiest solutions are overlooked.. If you write this as an answer I will mark it as an answer

Comment: @horcrux: Please post an answer.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Why did you removed yours? We posted in the same time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may wrap  the pattern with word boundaries and capture exactly 2 digits into Group 2:

```
\b(\d{1,2})(\d{2})\b
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/frwKEX/2)

- `\b` - intial word boundary
- `(\d{1,2})` - Group 1 capturing one or two digits
- `(\d{2})`  - Group 2 matching exactly 2 digits
- `\b` - trailing word boundary.

Comment: While your answer perfectly answers the question, and yes it works, I would like to go with horcrux. He answered the real overlooked solution.